# Animated scroll using JavaScript without scrollInToView function

Tags: javascript

I am using `scrollIntoView` for soft scrolling and better UX in one of my projects.
This function do not support duration and I want do scroll under **100 millisecond** because Google search console report warning for **FID** (First Input Delay) in all pages that using it. I need pure JS function (no jQuery or other libraries) for animate scroll to element with duration support.
I do not want instant scrolling.